# Unable to find out accurate price difference for products without discount

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to calculate price difference of product, but I am not able to calculate the difference for a product who doesn't have any discount on it.

My code is:

```java
package Tekbakertest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

public class Ted_sale 
{
    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Chrome\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        //System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
        prefs.put("password_manager_enabled", false); 
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("http://www.tedbaker.com/");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a")));

        if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a")).isDisplayed())
        {

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a")).click();

        }
        Actions act=new Actions(driver);
        WebElement Category=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='categories_nav']/li[1]/a"));
        WebElement Sales_clothng=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='categories_nav']/li[1]/nav/div[1]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[3]/a"));
        act.moveToElement(Category).moveToElement(Sales_clothng).click().build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        List<WebElement> Product_list=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='name']"));

        System.out.println(Product_list.size());

        for(int i=0;i<Product_list.size();i++)
        {
            List<String> Product_list_lst = new ArrayList<String>();
            Product_list_lst.add(Product_list.get(i).getText());
            System.out.println(Product_list.get(i).getText());
        }

        for (WebElement items_product : Product_list)
        {
            System.out.println(items_product.getText());
        }
        System.out.println("Originanal Price of items");

        List<WebElement> Original_price=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='price previous']"));

        System.out.println(Original_price.size());

        for(int i=0;i<Original_price.size();i++)
        {
            List<String> Original_price_lst = new ArrayList<String>();
            Original_price_lst.add(Original_price.get(i).getText());
            System.out.println(Original_price.get(i).getText());
        }
        System.out.println("Discounted Price of items");

        List<WebElement> Discounted_price=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='price unit']"));

        System.out.println(Discounted_price.size());

        for(int i=0;i<Original_price.size();i++)
        {
            List<String> Discounted_price_lst = new ArrayList<String>();

            Discounted_price_lst.add(Discounted_price.get(i).getText());
            System.out.println(Discounted_price.get(i).getText());
        }

        for(int i=0;i<Discounted_price.size();i++)
        {
            List<String> Original_price_lst_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> Discounted_price_lst_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            String original_price_removecurrencysymbol = Original_price.get(i).getText().substring(1,Original_price.get(i).getText().length());
            String discount_price_removecurrencysymbol = Discounted_price.get(i).getText().substring(1,Discounted_price.get(i).getText().length());
            System.out.println(original_price_removecurrencysymbol);
            System.out.println(discount_price_removecurrencysymbol);
            int difference = Integer.parseInt(original_price_removecurrencysymbol) -Integer.parseInt(discount_price_removecurrencysymbol);
            System.out.println("Difference is:"+difference);
            if(difference>=50)
            {

                Product_list.get(i).click();
                // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'add_to_cart')]")).click();
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

The error is:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 59, Size: 59
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
        at Tekbakertest.Ted_sale.main(Ted_sale.java:92)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is your output when the error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Your stacktrace says you have an [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) in line 92. Here, you try to access index 59, although the list only has a size of 59 (note that indices start with 0, not 1).

Although I can not verify where line 92 exactly is, it looks like the last invocation of:

```
Product_list.get(i).click();
```

Where the surrounding loop is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Discounted_price.size(); i++)
```

You use the size of `Discounted_price` to iterate over `Product_list`, but the sizes of both lists are not equal.

As a side note: your code is really hard to read. Try out the formatter capabilites of your IDE and have a look at [Java's naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). This will make maintenance a lot easier.